# Second eshell buffer is opened at the top instead of bottom

Tags: emacs, elisp

### Desired function algorithm

```
|------------------|
| old buffer - 70% |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|------------------|
|                  |
| eshell - 30%     |
|------------------|
```

1. If there is only 1 window in the buffer

   1.1 Split buffer into 2 parts: top - 70% of the height, bottom - 30% of the height.

   1.2. Put cursor to the bottom buffer.

   1.3. Open eshell.

### Code

```
(defun new-eshell ()
  (interactive)
  (when (one-window-on-screen-p)
    (let ((new-window (split-window-vertically 30)))
      (select-window new-window)
      (eshell "eshell"))))

(defun one-window-on-screen-p ()
  (= (length (window-list)) 1))

(global-set-key "\M-e" 'new-eshell)
```

### Problem

When I click `Alt-e` for the first time, the function works correctly. But if I hide eshell buffer, and click `Alt-e` for the second time, the window is split in proportions 50/50 and `"*eshell<2>*"` buffer is opened at the top instead of bottom.

Comment: Can't reproduce on 24.3.50.1

Comment: @abo-abo Mine is 24.2.1. Does my function work correctly for you?

Comment: Yes, as far as i can tell.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that the parameter of `split-lines-vertically` refers to a number of lines, not to a proportion.  This code worked for me:

```
(defun new-eshell ()
  (interactive)
  (when (one-window-on-screen-p)
    (let* ((lines (window-body-height))
           (new-window (split-window-vertically (floor (* 0.7 lines)))))
      (select-window new-window)
      (eshell "eshell"))))
```

(btw, I obtained strange results if I passed a floating point number to `split-lines-vertically`, so I had to use `floor`)

Comment: This fixed the proportion, but for me the second eshell buffer is still opened at the top.

Comment: I could not reproduce that behavior (emacs 24.3, eshell 21.1).  Does that happen to you even with emacs -Q?

Comment: "Does that happen to you even with emacs -Q?" - yes